# Loss of data, in extended class when converting to JSON string

Tags: java, json, gson, extend

There is a parent class and a child class that extends it. I have set the values as mentioned in code below, inside Lion class and added it to a list of Animals object. "Type" is part of Animals class and "Name" is part of Lion class.  But while converting to JSON data in Lion class ("Name") is getting lost. How to solve this issue?

```
  public class Animals implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String type;

        //getters and setters
    }
    public class Lion extends Animals implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String name;

        //getters and setters
    }
    public class Zoo implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private List<Animals> listOfAnimals;

        //getters and setters
    }
    //method to implement logic
    public String  createZoo(){

    Lion lion= new Lion();
    Zoo zoo=new Zoo();
    List<Animals> list= new ArrayList<Animals>();

    lion.setName("Alex");
    lion.setType("Mammal");
    list.add(lion); //which should be working fine since Lion extends Animal
    zoo.setListOfAnimals(list);

    //converting to JSON
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(zoo);
    return jsonString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked when I changed the Gson jar to 2.8.5 version. Previously I was using 1.4 version, which was having this issue.